# Reading Invalid Data

Tags: c++, windows

I got this warning when i compile my program

> Reading invalid data from "revval": the readable size is 'revsize*4 bytes, but '8' bytes may be read

There's too many similar warning appear in my warning list. Its about 6 of them. But all of those looks similar like this code below. Only the variable changed.

Here's the piece of code from my whole program

```
int revsize = 0;
int* revval;

string revlist[30];
revval = new int[revsize];

system("cls");

cout << "\nHow many revenue do you want to calculate : ";
cin >> revsize;

if (revsize > 0) {
    for (int p = 0; p < revsize; p++) {
        cout << "Enter the name of the expense : ";
        cin >> revlist[p];

        cout << revlist[p] << " : ";
        cin >> revval[p];
        revtotal += revval[p];
    }
}
```

how to get rid of this warning? i try initialize all the variable before but its doesnt seem to work.

Comment: Tip: Don't use C arrays, use `std::vector<std::string>`. This avoids asking questions like "How many?" because you don't care, just keep adding until someone types a blank line or something like that. This goes double for using `new[]`. Unless you fully understand the consequences of that sort of approach, avoid it. Use `std::vector<int>` instead. Even better, make a simple `struct` with a `std::string` and `int` property, then add *those* to your vector.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allocate the dynamic array after the first input `revsize`, I suggest using `vector` to avoid manage memory by hand. Use `vector<string>` to avoid use a fix-sized array, it's much more smooth, the size can be larger than the `30` magic number in your program.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main() {
  int revsize = 0;

  std::vector<std::string> revlist;
  int revtotal = 0;

  // system("cls");

  cout << "\nHow many revenue do you want to calculate : ";
  cin >> revsize;
  std::vector<int> revval;

  if (revsize > 0) {
    for (int p = 0; p < revsize; p++) {
      cout << "Enter the name of the expense : ";
      std::string name;
      cin >> name;
      revlist.push_back(std::move(name));

      cout << revlist[p] << " : ";

      int val;
      cin >> val;
      revval.push_back(val);
      revtotal += revval[p];
    }
  }
  std::cout << "sum:" << revtotal << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```